# Why do images appear behind previous images when trying to put new images into a Pygame display?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, blit

I'm testing out pygame (in python 2.7) before I try to use it in any programs, what I am trying to do is make an image appear in the display, wait for half a second, then cover the previous image with a new one, but the second image is not placed on top of the old image, but underneath it. I tried switching the image order, using different images, and even tried using 3 images.

```
import time as t
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000),0,32)
image1 = pygame.image.load("image1.png").convert_alpha()
image2 = pygame.image.load("image2.png").convert()
while True:
    screen.blit(image1,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    t.sleep(0.5)
    screen.blit(image2,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Your image2 _is_ appearing in front of image1. But a split second later, you go back to the start of the `while` loop and draw another image1 in front of it. If you don’t want that, get rid of the while loop. If you want that, but only after a half-second delay, do another `sleep` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. Cant believe I didn't spot that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem; we all make silly mistakes like that. I think this can be closed as a harmless typo question, but just in case others disagree, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `image2` does in fact appearing in front of your `image1`. But only for a split second.

Immediately after you `update` the display, you go back to the start of the `while` loop, which immediately blits another copy of `image1` in front of `image2`.

If you wanted these to alternate back and forth every half second, you just need to add another `sleep` at the end of the loop.

If you wanted it to just draw `image1`, wait, draw `image2`, and be done with it, just get rid of the `while` loop.